# Angular multi-page routing - client or server side?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, url-routing

I am building a multi-page Angular app backed with node.js and express.

My question is when should I use Angular routing and not Express routing if I don't have single page URL changes?

My understanding is that if different pages are loaded, the routing should be made by the server. On the other hand, if the DOM is manipulated with Ajax then Angular should do the job. Is this the case even if the URL doesn't change?

And when I want to load HTML partials into different pages I should render them in the server (for example by EJS?) and that way I'll avoid some SEO problems?